# SQL query to returns invalid postcodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written a query that returns invalid postcodes on our database, see below. It works well except the output is still returning values for the first two lines --Special Case.

The first one `GIR 0AA` is an actual postcode that exists but does not meet the conventional formatting and should therefore be excluded altogether. The second one are British Forces postcodes that begin with `BFPO` followed by a space then a number between 1 and 500. These also need to be excluded from the output where they meet the specified criteria.

I suspect my formatting is not quite right, so can any of you help me out?

Thanks in advance.

```
-- Returns invalid postcodes

SELECT house_name, address, town, county, postcode

FROM Addresses

WHERE

-- Special case GIR 0AA

patindex('[GIR] [0AA]', postcode) = 0 and -- Need to exclude these from results

-- Special case Static British Forces Post Offices (BFPO)

patindex('[BFPO] [1-500]', postcode) = 0 and --Need to exclude these from results

-- AANN NAA

patindex('[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]', postcode) = 0 and

-- AANA NAA

patindex('[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]', postcode) = 0 and

-- ANN NAA

patindex('[A-Z][0-9][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]', postcode) = 0 and

-- AAN NAA

patindex('[A-Z][A-Z][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]', postcode) = 0 and

-- ANA NAA

patindex('[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]', postcode) = 0 and

-- AN NAA

patindex('[A-Z][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]', postcode) = 0


ORDER BY postcode ASC
```

Comment: Can you provide come examples of real data and expected results?

Comment: [GIR] is any one of those characters.  If you want to match on GIR then match on GIR.

Comment: just checking.. Should you be using `OR` in your where clause instead of the `AND` ?

Answer (score 3):

First, you are using `patindex()` when `like` makes much more sense.  `Like` is standard SQL and what one "expects" in this context.

Second, you are misusing the `[]` construct.  This provides a list of characters that match individually.  So `[GIS]` will match `'G'`, `'I'`, and `'S'`, but not `'GIS'`.

```
WHERE -- Special case GIR 0AA
      postcode <> 'GIR 0AA' and -- Need to exclude these from results
      postcode not like 'PFPO [0-9][0-9][0-9]' and
      postcode not like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' and
      postcode not like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' and
      postcode not like '[A-Z][0-9][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' and
      postcode not like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' and
      postcode not like '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'and
      postcode not like '[A-Z][0-9] [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'
```

If the postcode is embedded in a longer string, you might want `'%'` at the beginning, end, or beginning and end of the pattern.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I really appreciate your advice. I will take a look at what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a bit more specific.  By saying `patindex('[BFPO] [1-500]', postcode)` you expect it to check for any number from 1 to 500, but that is not how `PATINDEX` works. Similarly, for `GIR 0AA`, there is no reason to use `PATINDEX` since it is a very specific case.  This worked in my minimal testing:

```
Where   patindex('BFPO [1-9]', postcode) = 0
    And patindex('BFPO [1-9][0-9]', postcode) = 0
    And patindex('BFPO [1-4][0-9][0-9]', postcode) = 0
    And postcode <>'BFPO 500'
    And postcode <> 'GIR 0AA'
```

Break up `BFPO 1-500` into four distinct possibility ranges: 1-9, 10-99, 100-499, and 500.  Then check specifically for `GIR 0AA`.

Answer (score 0):

`patindex('[GIR] [0AA]', postcode) = 0` actually searches for a string consisting of a 'G' an 'I' or an 'R' followed by a space then a '0' an 'A' or an 'A'. So `patindex('[GIR] [0AA]', 'G 0')`  would return 1 as would `patindex('[GIR] [0AA]', 'R A')`.

What you actually need is either:

```
postcode <> 'GIR 0AA'
```

or

```
patindex('[G][I][R] [0][A][A]', 'GIR 0AA') = 0
```

or

```
patindex('GIR 0AA', 'GIR 0AA') = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, I am still a newbie when it comes to SQL so your advice is really appreciated.